# Getting Error while creating new project in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have just installed Xamarin and create simple new project. After just creation of project I am getting error like:

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Are your target frameworks and target versions compatible (i.e. the same android version)? This looks like the framework is newer than the target version. There's a blog [here](https://xamarinsharp.com/2017/05/01/xamarin-android-support-design-25-3-1-is-not-compatible-with-xamarin-forms-2-3-4-231-constraint-xamarin-android-support-design-23-3-0-how-to-fix-it/) that seems to describe a similar problem.

Comment: Yes, still getting error.

Comment: What JDK version is installed? 1.7, 1.8?

Comment: Another [link](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2016/12/06/NuGet-does-my-head-in%E2%80%A6-No-thanks-to-XamarinForms.aspx) that might help.

Comment: JDK version 1.8

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the target framework for compile to “Android 7.1(Nougat)”.

Here are Steps to change the target compile framework :
 Right Click on Android Project -> Properties

[image]

Current Android application properties(Compile using Android 6.0)

[image]

Change Compile Android Version to Android 7.1 (Nougat)

[image]

When Change the target compilation version of Android , Visual Studio will ask you to restart the project to configure itself…
"Yes" to close and reopen , after the reboot go to NuGet package manager to update Android packages and Select Android Packages v.25.3.1.. when the update ends Re-Build the project